# How can I extend vue-validator?

Tags: javascript, components, vue.js

I would like to be able to extend vue-validator to be able to abstract out common functionality between forms (such as loading spinners, and retrieving server side errors).

I took a stab at it using the following:

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="submitForm" novalidate>
    <loader size="medium" v-if="isSubmittingForm"></loader>
    <slot></slot>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
import Validator from 'vue-validator';

export default {
  extends: Validator,

  data() {
    return {
      isSubmittingForm: false
    }
  },

  methods: {
    submitForm() {
    }
  }
}
```

But I get an error `Cannot read property 'components' of undefined`. Is there a way to extend `vue-validator` like this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to one of two things. 
1. Create a component that includes your common functionality and extend it using the vue.extends hook, or, 
2. better option IMHO, wrap all the shared properties, methods etc into an object literal and turn it into a mixin.

http://vuejs.org/guide/mixins.html